# How to Count the Number of Ranges That Occur Between Certain Cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, count, range

[Here is the dropbox file to the excel workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aoj8109q51w1wom/Self-Track_Stack.xlsx?dl=0)

I am trying to count the number of times a RANGE of cells occurs that does not contain the text "Relapse" inside of it.

So for example, the first range would be between I12 and I23, since it has no values up until cell I24 which contains "Relapse"

The second range would thus be from I26 to I163, again since this range does not contain "Relapse"

I would like to count the number of times these ranges occur, so that in this case the expected value that is to be returned is simply 2 because there are 2 existing ranges within the range selected that do not contain "Relapse" in the cells.

Comment: @pnuts sorry but what is a helper column?

Comment: @pnuts Oh, then in that case I wouldn't mind. I can just hide it, right?

Comment: @pnuts Just the string "Relapse" occurs. So anytime "Relapse" is in a cell I would like count the range itself that occurred between the last time there was a cell that contained "relapse." 

Otherwise its just notes on the days

Answer (score 0):

Please try in J2 (J being  helper column) and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(AND(I2="Relapse",J1="",I3<>"Relapse"),MAX(J$1:J1)+1,"")
```

Should assign an index at the end of each group and increment by one each time.

If you want the result visible but the column hidden, remove  `MAX(J$1:J1)+` and `=SUM(J:J)` wherever suits.

Comment: If I followed your instructions correctly then the "helper column" in my case would have to be column 'K' no?

Comment: "If you want the result visible but the column hidden, remove  MAX(J$1:J1)+ and =SUM(J:J) wherever suits."

I'm not sure if I follow suit here... I insert =SUM(J:J) instead of MAX(J$1:J1)+ ?

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not well versed in excel. I am trying to follow your instructions step by step.